# Angular2 and Typescript how to make the field get cleared and get editable in respective popup using Angular2 and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Hai i have a address field, wherein in add popup field i want the address field to be empty when i open the new popup but now it is prefilled with the previously entered address and in edit field i want the address of that particular row to be editable but now it is empty.

HTML:

ADD PopUP:

```
 <button (click)="add()"> </button>
```

Address Field:

```
<ng4geo-autocomplete [userSettings]="settings" (componentCallback)="autoCompleteCallback2($event)"></ng4geo-autocomplete>
```

EDit field:

```
<button  (click)="edit(page)"></button>
```

Ts:

```
add() {
  this.new_page = new NewPage();
  this.addPage.show();
}

edit(page) {
    this.editPage.show();
    this.edit_page = page;
}
autoCompleteCallback2(selectedData:any) {
    this.address=selectedData.data.formatted_address;
    this.location=selectedData.data.geometry.location;
    }
```

Comment: show the `settings` object

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka : public settings: any = {
  showRecentSearch: false,
  showSearchButton:false,
  inputPlaceholderText: 'Address'
};